# Vue3 : jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a Vue 3 app.

I've install jQuery + Bootstrap and included them in main.js like this:

```js
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

global.jQuery = require('jquery');
const $ = global.jQuery;
window.$ = $;
```

I have a view called AdminView, contains product list, and a child component called "ProductModal"

This is the AdminView component

```html
<template>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tp-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <h3>All Products</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-end">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" @click='createProductRequest'>Create Product</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Desc</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="(product, ind) in productList" :key="ind">
                <th scope="row">{{ ind + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.price }} DH</td>
                <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary me-1">Edit</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger me-1">Delete</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-dark me-1">+</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>wa zabiii</h1>
  <product-modal ref="productModal"></product-modal>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import ProductService from "../services/productService";
import ProductModal from "../components/Product";
import jquery from "jquery";
const $ = jquery;
window.$ = $;

export default {
  name: "AdminView",
  components: { ProductModal },
  data() {
    return {
      productList: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(jQuery);
    ProductService.getAllProducts()
      .then((response) => {
        this.productList = response.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    createProductRequest() {
      this.$refs["productModal"].showProductModel();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the ProductModal component :

```html
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="productModal" tabIndex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form
          @submit.prevent="saveProduct"
          novalidate
          :class="submitted ? 'was-validated' : ''"
        >
         ........
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import Product from "@/models/products";
import ProductService from "@/services/productService";
import $ from "jquery";


export default {
  name: "product-modal",
  data() {
    return {
      product: new Product(),
      errorMessage: {},
      submit: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveProduct() {
      ProductService.saveProduct(this.product)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          $("#productModal").modal("hide");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          (this.errorMessage = " error occurred"), console.log(err);
        });
    },
    showProductModel() {
      console.log("shild component");      
      $('#productModal').modal('show');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When I try to click on 'create product' button , to activate jquery modal function, this error occurred:

```
jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).modal is not a function
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).modal is not a function
  at Proxy.showProductModel
```

These are the dependencies in package.json

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "expose-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery with Vue.  There is nothing jQuery can do that you can't do with just Vue and modern vanilla JS.  It frequently leads to conflicts when using both jQuery and Vue so it's best to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for your advice; that's exactly what I'm considering doing right now. Your insights have been very helpful